# AG Grid, using tree formatted data and filtering by non leaf nodes

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am providing tree formatted data to the grid. When I used the in column filters, it applies the filters to the leaf nodes and shows parent nodes where needed to provide a path to the leafs.

I am looking for a way to allow the user to provide a quick filter along with the column filters. The quick filter would filter out all non-leaf nodes that do not contain the filter text. End result would be that the user could filter out non-leaf nodes with the quick filter, then filter down to leaf nodes with the column filter.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I realize I could filter the tree data and pass it pre-filtered to the grid, but I really need to find a way to implement this while still passing the entire unfiltered tree data to the grid.

Is this possible? If not, could I somehow hide a non-leaf node manually without removing it from the tree data model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have seen this enhancement request on github...

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/110

I took the example that was created there and modified it with an [`externalFilter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0). Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0weguLr/2/) as an example.

Here's the process for the external filter:

1. When an input is changed, inform the grid by calling `gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged()`
2. Let the grid know that an external filter is present by setting `gridOptions.isExternalFilterPresent` to `true`
3. `gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass` will then be called on each **`node`** - It is important to note that it is called on each node... a group isn't considered a node, only the leaf elements
4. Each node contains data for it's parent via `node.parent`, so check the parent's group name if it contains the filter text, in the example this looks like: `node.parent.data.group.includes($scope.filter)` which if true then that **node** will remain in the grid.

This example only shows one level deep... if you have groups within groups, then the logic in `doesExternalFilterPass` will get more complicated by being recursive in checking the parent's parent's name, but that logic shouldn't be too terrible...

Also, if you have any groups that don't have children, they will automatically be filtered out since they don't really have nodes to display/be filtered on.

Comment: I actually did come across that example after I posted this and came to the same conclusion. To make the recursiveness more performant I am adding a path property to each node as it iterates them in getNodeChildDetails, then in the external filtrer I can just check if path contains xyz. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JarodMoser Thanks! Already vote up, although I am looking for another issue. Ag-grid how to automatically expand the leaf nodes when using quick filter.